# AD B2C test user flow does not allow selection of application registration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I setup a new tenant and registered an application and created a secret following the tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga

I created a sign-in/ sign-up user flow. When I try and test run the user flow, the application is not in the drop down.

I then registered another app registration using the legacy flow from the tutorial. When I test the user flow now the 2nd app registration is in the list and I can execute the flow without issue.

Has anyone else experienced this? Why is the first app registration not showing up in the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the 6th step:

> 6. Under **Supported account types**, select **Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with
>    user flows)**.

If you didn't select this one, the application won't be listed in the drop down. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Still getting up to speed on some of these settings.

Comment: I did it, but still nothing in application selection list.

Comment: Couldn't change to that setting, but deleting and remaking worked fine.